# Vuejs suggest to use const and let. But both are not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working with Vuejs. I am trying to export a variable so vuejs is suggesting to use const instead of let.
But I need to change the variable in a function . This is not allowed as const cannot be changed. Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Without context this question is hard to answer. Could you provide something that resembles a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So basically I am trying to use a variable across files . in file1.vue I have
`let val=1;
export {val}

val++; //modifying val
`
Here its not allowing to export as let so i should use const
When I use const `val++` is not going to work which is to modify, but I need to modify

Comment: Far too vague and approximate as a question. Please make more effort and be sure to understand the basics of JS (this question has nothing to do with Vue per-se).

Comment: @kissu vue is only restricting me to use const instead of let

Comment: Vue does not do such things. Is it an ESlint rule? Some compiler warning seen in your browser console? Something else? If you're exporting a function, `const` will be fine anyway. As you can see, the context is quite blurry here. [ask]

Comment: i disabled eslint . Still the same dilemma from the compiler

Comment: @kissu I cannot use const as I need to update it as well

Comment: Too vague x2 still. Not sure how you expect us to help you here. [ask]

Comment: Vue can't suggest anything. It doesn't care about JS that you write, it's ui framework. It's something in your toolchain, primarily a linter. ES modules themselves are allowed to have `let` exports, it's totally legit. I'm voting to close because the question isn't constructive in its current form. Consider reasking with relevant details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765194/conditionally-initializing-a-constant-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are trying to **reuse** a variable by importing it into multiple vue components. This is not the use that should be made of js modules. I suggest you look at this library through which you can share the status between multiple components in a very simple way:

https://pinia.vuejs.org/